# How to upgrade Service Fabric Tools to 1.6?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-service-fabric

I previously had Service Fabric SDK and tools 5.4/2.4 installed. I used the downloader directly from Service Fabric's "Prepare your development environment" page and successfully installed "Microsoft Azure Service Fabric SDK and Tools - 2.6.210 (VS2015)". However I can no longer load my application. Visual Studio gives an error that the project has a higher version "1.6" but I only have "Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Visual Studio Tools 1.4" installed. This partly makes sense because another team member recently upgraded the branch after having a hard drive failure and doing a clean install of everything from scratch. Is there any way to install version 1.6 of the Visual Studio 2015 tools?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the tools? Are you sure that this is the problem and it's not just it whinging about not being able to find the old MSBuild package? If it's the latter you have to manually edit the sfproj file and update the paths from 1.x to 1.6.

Comment: @Mardoxx no, I think it was looking for the newer version which did not get installed. I was able to uninstall multiple things from Control Panel and try again successfully (see my answer below).

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: Uninstall first.

I belive the installer for "Microsoft Azure Service Fabric SDK and Tools - 2.6.210 (VS2015)" is only able to upgrade 2 of the 3 things it installs. Looking at control panel I see these three things listed with different dates.

- Microsoft Azure Service Fabric (new version)
- Microsoft Azure Service Fabric SDK (new version)
- Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Tools for Visual Studio 2015 (old version)

I assumed that these 3 things were installed by "Microsoft Azure Service Fabric SDK and Tools - 2.6.210 (VS2015)" so I uninstalled them and ran the web platform installer again. It did infact install all 3 and they now have the expected versions.